No se me envian los datos del formulario al correo
tengo un pequeño formulario que estoy probando para rellenarlo y enviarlo a un correo de un dominio que tengo pero parece que se envia pero nunca llega el correo.
Aqui dejo el codigo para ver si alguien sabe que puedo estar haciendo mal. He intentado diferentes configuraciones incluso haciendo uso un poco de chat gpt y no detecto donde esta el error.
No se mucho de PHP y seguramente alli esta el fallo que no puedo detectar.
 <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="send_mail.php">
        <label for="name">Nombre:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>

        <label for="email">Correo Electrónico:</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>

        <label for="message">Mensaje:</label><br>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(this);

            fetch("send_mail.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Mensaje enviado correctamente";
            })
            .catch(error => {
                document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Error al enviar el mensaje";
            });
        });
    </script>


<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$to = "info@miweb.com";  // Cambia esta línea por tu correo
$subject = "Nuevo mensaje de formulario de contacto";

$name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
$email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
$message = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['message']));

// Validación de email
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Dirección de correo no válida.";
    exit;
}

$headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n" .
           "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n" .
           "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";

$email_body = "
    <h2>Nuevo Mensaje de Contacto</h2>
    <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> $name</p>
    <p><strong>Correo Electrónico:</strong> $email</p>
    <p><strong>Mensaje:</strong><br>$message</p>
";

if (mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers)) {
    echo "El mensaje se ha enviado correctamente.";
} else {
    echo "Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje.";
}
} else {
echo "Método no permitido";
}
?>

El mensaje de enviado correctamente aparece en el formulario pero el correo nunca llega.
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda

Cambia esto mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers) por esto: mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers, "-fmiemail@midominio.com") para que te llegen los rebotes a miemail@midominio.com y puedas averiguar si los correos son rechazados en algun punto y con que error.  Es decir, usa el quinto parámetro con  "-f" para forzar la cabecera Return-path al usar la función mail()

Gracias por tu respuesta, he puesto lo que me has comentado y no llega ningun correo, he probado poniendo tambien un correo personal de gmail a ver si llegaban de esa manera y tampoco llegan.

¿Eso desde donde lo mandas?  ¿desde un hosting? ¿desde un pc local?  ¿linux, windows?  Si lo mandas desde un hosting asegúrate que permitan enviar correos. Si es desde un pc local será dificil de seguir, pero tendrias que poderlo seguir en tu archivo /var/log/maillog y ver donde fue enviado (eso si es un linux).

Y luego está el tema del SPF/DKIM/DMARC del dominio del "to:" que estés usando, que quizas ese dominio tiene una política restrictiva de DMARC y ni consigan pasar a los inbox de destino, ni tampoco ser devueltos correctamente por el mismo motivo, y se tiren dias en las colas de algun servidor que no consigue entregartelo hasta que sea eliminado automáticamente.

Gracias de nuevo por tus respuestas, la verdad que pense que iban a tardar 500 años en contestarme me ha sorprendido la web, eso lo estoy mandando desde un hosting, especificamente IONOS que en principio el soporte me ha dicho que no tienen restricciones para hacer esto. La verdad que no me imagine que seria tanto lio mandar por correo a un correo propio del mismo hosting 3 lineas de texto de un formulario xDDDD

Si es el mismo hosting no tendrias que tener problema, pues no sale del propio servidor. Si la función mail() te devuelve un true entonces tiene que estar sí o sí en tu bandeja de entrada del mismo servidor, a menos que: 1) Tengas el registro MX de tu dominio apuntando a otra parte, ya sea en el DNS de IONOS de tu servidor o bien en un nameserver externo que estés usando, o bien 2) Sea considerado spam y lo tengas en otra carpeta.

Gracias voy a comprobar eso que me dices porque la direccion que uso de envio pertenece al propio dominio incluso lei unas notas en iones para usar una libreria phpmailer configurando el smtp y tampoco me ha funcionado asi que entiendo que puede ser un fallo de ionos en mi dominio o ya no se que otro problema podria ser porque no deberia ser tan complicado es un formulario no una base de datos ni nada parecido.

Dudo que sea un fallo de IONOS... Si usas linux o tienes acceso a el de algun modo, ejecuta el comando "dig +short midominio.com MX" para ver que servidores MX tienes configurados.  Para que te llege al mismo servidor deberia aparecer el... sin embargo, si usas google o cosas de terceros entonces seguramente el problema esté en tu registro SPF, que puedes consultar con "dig midominio,com TXT" y buscar a ver si te aparece una línea que empiece por "v=SPF1" (esa es la linea del SPF de tu dominio)

He contactado con IONOS que era el hosting que estoy usando, basicamente no sabian muy bien cual era el fallo, me dijo que creara un php.ini para que el server generara un log con los fallos, no se si es casualidad o que ellos tocaron algo del correo pero empezo a funcionar el formulario.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Vaya, pues si que era un fallo de IONOS pues... pues vale, me alegro que ahora te funcione. Saludos!

Gracias por tu ayuda, aun asi con lo que tu me enviaste tenia algunas cosas que pude mejorar en el codigo.
